# How to use the golden spiral composition rule

Tags: modeling, scripting

We've all heard of this magical thing called the golden spiral, which derives from the golden ratio; However, I feel like there's a general confusion around how to use it in the composition of an image.

[image]

This image includes both the golden spiral and the golden triangles.

The golden spiral is a logarithmic spiral where the growth factor is φ (phi); Where is the positive root of:

[image]

Which is, by defenition:

[image]

This pattern is present all throughout nature, since the ratio of two consecutive numbers in the [Fibonacci sequence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_number) tends towards φ.

So, how does one apply this rule to the composition of an image?

Comment: http://digital-photography-school.com/divine-composition-with-fibonaccis-ratio-the-rule-of-thirds-on-steroids/ Has some nice illustrations.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about blender.

Comment: Andrew price actually just came out with a new [composition video](http://www.blenderguru.com/tutorials/understanding-composition/#.VERpSZUtDX4) that discusses the golden spiral along with many other composition topics.

Comment: @PGmath I know, but he does a bad job at explaining it.

Comment: From what I gather, you want to put the main focal element at the limit of the spiral, and some guiding lines along the spiral itself and along BD and CE.

Comment: @PGmath the focal element at the \*center\* of the spiral.

Comment: Yes, the center being the intersection of BD and CE.  To explain it mathematically would require too much math for a comment, sorry!  You sound like you know quite a bit about the math anyhow (a little calc I) correct?

Comment: I've written a [meta post](http://meta.blender.stackexchange.com/q/497/599) to discuss whether these should be on or off topic.